# Variable value display without page reload

Tags: python, ajax, pyramid

I am trying to write a simple website. Here is the requirement.

1. The site needs to be made with Pyramid web framework
2. There needs to be a thread that contains 3 variables and the values of the variables will  keep on changing.
3. The site needs to pick these values up and display them without reloading the page.

I know I need to use some form of AJAX. Please suggest me some ways to do this. Even links to some tutorials will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use long polling now and it seems like the best thing to use for me

Answer (score 1):

I would use [pubnub](http://www.pubnub.com/), to broadcast the changes to the variables. Dead simple and reliable. The other alternative is rolling your own which requires running the push portion of the app on a server designed to handle long polling/websockets which you can do with pyramid and [gevent/socketio](https://github.com/abourget/pyramid_socketio). But you would be building the equivalent of what pubnub offers and it may or may not meet your scalability requirements.